# C++ Segmentation fault core dumped for simple vector operation

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

I have the following code c++ code

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define for_loop(upper_bound) for (int i=0;i<upper_bound; ++i)

// #define SHOW_VECTOR(vec_in) for(int j=0;j<vec_in.size();j++){ cout << vec_in[j] << " " << endl;};


int main(){
    int dim_1=10;
    int dim_2=3;

    int outer_i;
    // vector variable declared here to have 10 values
    vector<vector<int>>vec_var(dim_1);

    for_loop(dim_1){
        outer_i = i;
        for_loop(dim_2){
            cout << outer_i << " " << i << endl;

            vec_var[outer_i][i]=103;    
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I try and run it i get the following error:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: I would strongly recommend against defining custom macros like this, it gets messy quickly. If you want a simpler syntax for a for loop, try range-based for: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/range-based-loop-c/

Comment: @JanPokorný thanks jan point taken will improve on this one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to size both your outer and inner vectors

```
vector<vector<int>> vec_var(dim_1, vector<int>(dim_2));
//                                 ^ inner vector default size
```

Otherwise as written, you have an outer vector if size `dim_1` but all of the inner vectors are empty.

As an aside, since I notice you then filling the vector with constant values, you can do all that in one step too

```
vector<vector<int>> vec_var(dim_1, vector<int>(dim_2, 103));
//                                                    ^ default of inner vector elements
```

Comment: Thanks Cory big help

Answer (score 4):

Subscripting a `std::vector` does not cause that element position to be created.  You need to resize, push_back, or otherwise add elements to the vectors!  You indexed things that are out of range.

The outer vector is defined with a constructor argument that sizes it to `dim_1`, but each of those inner vectors does not have any elements.  So follow it up with:

```
for (auto& inner : vec_var)  inner.resize(dim_2);
```

Also, suggest using the built-in range-based `for` loop instead of your macro.  That you need to manually save the index in your outer loop shows that your macro is not really the most convenient!

```
int main()
{
constexpr int dim_1=10;
constexpr int dim_2=3;

vector<vector<int>>vec_var(dim_1);

for (auto& outer : vec_var) {
    outer.resize (dim_2);
    for (auto& inner : outer) {
        inner=103;    
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

But really, this is not normal.  You probably should be using `push_back` to add the values, rather than resizing it and then subscripting each element in order.

Comment: `foreach` -- When did `foreach` become a C++ keyword?  A ranged-based `for` loop is `for (auto& inner : vec_var)`

Comment: Sorry; that's from Boost, and was an imlementation by Eric Nablier of the (then upcoming) range for loop.

Comment: OK.  It did look boost-like.

Answer (score 1):

You only set the dimension of the outer vector. You need to set the dimension of the inner vectors as well.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define for_loop(upper_bound) for (int i=0;i<upper_bound; ++i)

// #define SHOW_VECTOR(vec_in) for(int j=0;j<vec_in.size();j++){ cout << 
vec_in[j] << " " << endl;};


int main(){
  int dim_1=10;
  int dim_2=3;

  int outer_i;
  // vector variable declared here to have 10 values
  vector<vector<int>>vec_var(dim_1);

  for_loop(dim_1){
      outer_i = i;
      vec_var[outer_i].resize(dim_2); // ADD THIS
      for_loop(dim_2){
        cout << outer_i << " " << i << endl;

        vec_var[outer_i][i]=103;    
      }
  }

  return 0;
}
```